# How to add void/null as default argument to a function/lambda pointer, in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, function-pointers, default-arguments

**Present signature** is

```
template<class TypeData,typename TypeFunc>
bool isPrime(const TypeData& n,TypeFunc fSqrt,bool debug = false)
```

and this works perfectly with

```
std::cout<<(isPrime(n,fSqrt)?"Positive":"Negative")<<'\n';
```

But, my **intension** is something like

```
template<class TypeData,typename TypeFunc>
bool isPrime(const TypeData& n,TypeFunc fSqrt = nullptr,bool debug = false)
```

or

```
template<class TypeData,typename TypeFunc>
bool isPrime(const TypeData& n,TypeFunc fSqrt = NULL,bool debug = false)
```

to be called by

```
std::cout<<(isPrime(n)?"Positive":"Negative")<<'\n';
```

*Overloading* is not possible due to a *static variable* inside the function.
Only different `class TypeData` should give different *template-functions* for this *function-template*.

Please help me out with the proper syntax. If C++ does not support this, what is an alternative approach I can use?

**Compile Errors**

for `TypeFunc fSqrt = nullptr`

```
main.cpp:90:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘isPrime(int&)’
  std::cout<<(isPrime(n)?"Positive":"Negative")<<'\n';
                       ^
main.cpp:9:49: note: candidate: template bool isPrime(const TypeDate&, TypeFunc, bool)
 template<class TypeDate,typename TypeFunc> bool isPrime(const TypeDate& n,TypeFunc fSqrt = nullptr,bool debug = false) {
                                                 ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:9:49: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:90:23: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘TypeFunc’
  std::cout<<(isPrime(n)?"Positive":"Negative")<<'\n';
                       ^
```

for `TypeFunc fSqrt = NULL`

```
main.cpp:90:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘isPrime(int&)’
  std::cout<<(isPrime(n)?"Positive":"Negative")<<'\n';
                       ^
main.cpp:9:49: note: candidate: template bool isPrime(const TypeDate&, TypeFunc, bool)
 template<class TypeDate,typename TypeFunc> bool isPrime(const TypeDate& n,TypeFunc fSqrt = NULL,bool debug = false) {
                                                 ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:9:49: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:90:23: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘TypeFunc’
  std::cout<<(isPrime(n)?"Positive":"Negative")<<'\n';
                       ^
```

They are basically the same.

Comment: You could use a lambda to call you default sqrt function like `TypeFunc fSqrt = [](auto val){ return my_sqrt(val); }`

Comment: What will the function do when `fSqrt == nullptr`? Use a default function?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Will use fSqrt if available, else take a very different path. No default function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overloading actually *is* an option, you can let one overload call the other one:

```
template<class TypeData, typename TypeFunc>
bool isPrime(const TypeData& n, TypeFunc fSqrt, bool debug = false);

template<class TypeData>
bool isPrime(const TypeData& n, bool debug = false)
{
    using std::sqrt;
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<TypeData>)
    {
        return isPrime(n, static_cast<double(*)(double)>(sqrt), debug);
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<TypeData>)
    {
        return isPrime(n, static_cast<TypeData(*)(TypeData)>(sqrt), debug);
    }
    else
    {
        // this covers e.g. std::complex
        return isPrime(n, static_cast<TypeData(*)(TypeData const&)>(sqrt), debug);
        // for any other type we assume the overload accepts by
        // const reference as well (if there's one at all...)
        // if not, we still can fall back to the other overload
    }
}
```

This solution selects an appropriate square root function right away, something you would have had to solve anyway if the function argument had defaulted to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`std::identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/identity) as the default `TypeFunc` type.

```
#include <functional>

template<class TypeData,typename TypeFunc = std::identity>
bool isPrime(const TypeData& n,TypeFunc fSqrt = {}, bool debug = false) {
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<TypeFunc, std::identity>) return false;
  else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/TsWhGex1b)

If your compiler does not support C++20, you can just simply define your own `std::identity`:

```
struct Identity {
  template<class T>
  constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(T&& t) const noexcept {
    return std::forward<T>(t);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a default initialized `std::function` with the correct prototype for that:

```
template<class TypeData>
bool isPrime(const TypeData& n,std::function<const decltype(n)&(const decltype(n)&)> fSqrt={},bool debug = false)
```

You can then check in the function if it is valid or the default one by simply `if (fSqrt)`

full example: https://godbolt.org/z/zfMazebso

The prototype must be dependent only on the datatype of `n`, otherwise there is no default parameter possible, e.g., the compiler cannot deduce a type out of nothing.

Comment: It will compile now, but you are now making an expensive copy operation.  `std::function` uses type erasure, so there is going to need to be an allocation call when making the copy.  That may or may not matter, but it is something to avoid if possible.